# Number of tries to guess M-1 letters from M-letters-code

Tags: logical-deduction, combinatorics, locks

There are $N$ letters in an alphabet. There is a combination lock, the code to it consists from $M$ different letters.

You can input $M$ letters combination and try to open the lock. (But you can't check the lock unless you have inputted all $M$ letters).

If you guess at least $M-1$ letters from the code correctly the lock will be opened. The order of letters does not matter.

**How many** tries you need to guarantee that lock will be opened? How to find list of combinations you need to try?

---

P.S. I am especially interested for the case $N=32, M=4$.

Here is an example for the case $N=4, M=3$. The alphabet is "ABCD".
The answer is 1, with working combination "ABC". Indeed, if the code is different it can be different in $1$ letter only, therefore $M-1=2$ letters are always the same.

Comment: Well, for $N=2$ and certain values of $M$, [Hamming codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_code) should produce an optimal strategy. Every possible combination is either a valid message or 1 bit off from exactly one valid message, so you get the maximum possible use out of every attempt. I'm not sure whether Hamming codes generalize to non-binary alphabets or whether it's possible to improve on truncated Hamming codes for values of $M$ that don't fit the Hamming code construction.

Comment: Oh, wait, order doesn't matter. Are we drawing code letters with or without repetition?

Comment: @user2357112, please, read what is written carefully, otherwise I can't help you...

Comment: $M$ *different* letters, right.

Comment: Do you have to guess exactly $M-1$ letters, or will an exact match also open the lock?

Comment: @JoeZ., let's say it will...

Comment: The simple calculation is that there are $N \choose M$ codes, and each time you try $(N-M)(M-1)+1$ of them.  You can divide these and round up to find a lower bound for the number of tries.  The hard part is to find the combinations to try.  It may not be possible to achieve the lower bound.

Comment: @kaine:  Slight correction, it should be $(N-M)M+1$.  The codes you are checking are created by choosing one of $M$ letters to change.  You have $N-M$ letters to change it to.  Add the exact code you enter.  I don't think there is a binary case, as you have to select the letters without replacement and order doesn't matter.

Comment: For your case of $N=32, M=4$, there are ${32 \choose 4}=35960$ codes.  You try $28\cdot 4+1=113$ at a time, so you could hope to finish in $319$ tries.  I think overlap will increase it a bit.  I was working a bit on a greedy implementation-each time guess the remaining code that will rule out the maximum number of possibilities, but haven't got it working yet.

Answer (score 1):

I arrived at a relatively simple answer which assumes that one is not "clever" about cutting down the search space with strategic guesses. I'll discuss that a little more at the end.

The probability of choosing a winning combination is:

$( {M \choose M} + {M \choose M-1} )/ {N \choose M}$

i.e. The sum of either choosing all the numbers correctly and choosing all but one correctly. For your little example, this is $(1 + 3)/4 = 1$ - so you're guaranteed to win.

So, to answer the question itself, you would need to exhaust all the non-winning combinations first then the next one wins i.e. : ${N \choose M} - ( {M \choose M} + {M \choose M-1} )+1$ minimum attempts to guarantee unlocking.

Now, your challenge is essentially the game [Mastermind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_(board_game)) where N is the number of colours and M is the length of the code (with no repeats) and a win only requires M-1 (or M) pegs of any colour. The cumulative efforts of the world's minds have not come up with a neat formula for this, but Knuth came up with a 5-move strategy for standard Mastermind.

Comment: Doesn't the assume the non-winning combinations are unrelated? What if knowing that some set of combinations are all non-winning allows you to know that some other combinations you haven't yet tried won't win either?

Comment: You're right... thank you. I have added more.